# Hemingway's use of "benevolent" in "benevolent skin cancer"

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentence, from Hemigway's *The Old Man & the Sea*, I believe the author used the word *benevolent* when he meant to use the word *benign*.

> The brown blotches of the **benevolent** skin cancer the sun brings from
>   its reflection on the tropic sea were on his cheeks.

Have you ever seen this discussed anywhere? 
It would be difficult by any stretch of the imagination or poetry to believe the author purposely used benevolent in that sentence. Maybe he was drunk. :)

But it's also a bit difficult to believe his editor missed it. Of course, maybe the editor thought Papa purposely used the word and he didn't want to raise Papa's ire.

Here are some definitions of *benevolent* from merriam-webster.com

> 1 a :marked by or disposed to doing good – a benevolent donor
>
> b :organized for the purpose of doing good — a benevolent society
>
> 2 :marked by or suggestive of goodwill — benevolent smiles

Has benevolent changed meaning since the book was first published (1952)? 
Is it possible that *benevolent* was used, in 1952, in the same way that *benign* is used today?

Comment: Heya! This isn't a question about writing; it's a question about word meaning and usage, which should be squarely on topic and English Language and Usage. I'll migrate this over there :)

Comment: Interestingly, interpreting lyrics is off-topic, but interpreting prose? The question has merit with respect to intent to discern a possible definition. However, I doubt it can be answered authoritatively in an ELU context. My opinion is mine and may not necessarily reflect anyone else's.

Comment: On topic: I think this might have been used sarcastically. Or not: The context thinks that the idea of being in the sun is so good, the sun's markings are proof of it. Again, a different time where "sun spots" were a sign of healthiness.

Comment: This is very Hemingway-esque, the skin cancer is *a gift from the magnanimous Sun*.

Comment: This is totally literary interpretation, and ultimately unanswerable.

Comment: I don't know the full context, but perhaps he meant it metaphorically, referring to a dark tan as benevolent skin cancer?

Comment: Hardly proof, but Google ngram does show a crossover in the written popularity of the two words around 1970. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benign%2Cbenevolent&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbenign%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbenevolent%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary interpretation.

Comment: ... Yes; answers below include sensible guesses. But that's what they are.

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly more common to refer to any tumour or abnormality that is non-cancerous or non-life-threatening as *benign*, but *benign* and *benevolent* do not have the same implication.

[*Benign*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benign) implies that the thing being described is of no net detriment.

[*Benevolent*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benevolent) implies that the thing being described is of net benefit.

Though Hemingway undoubtedly knew of the general use of benign, and of course the meanings of the two words, I would suggest that Hemingway was using artistic license in this context in expressing that the blotchy abnormalities in question actively protected the character from the sun's rays (though in reality skin cancer does not protect in this way, and not all changes in skin pigmentation are cancerous). As such they were not merely of no net detriment, but were, instead, of net benefit. Hence the use of the word *benevolent*.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted.  I think it had some interesting points.

Comment: Thanks @daylight. Hopefully my edit will be enough to make whoever downvoted it change their mind, but without knowing their reason, obviously I can't address the issue directly.

Answer (score 4):

Being a dermatology healthcare provider and Hemingway lover, I actually think he misused the term cancer rather than benevolent being the word in question.

The description he includes in the text is more aligned with solar lentigos or “sun spots” that are brownish and come from sun exposure, and increase with age and years of exposure. These spots are benign, noncancerous, and and could easily be illustrated as benevolent spots from the sun, gifts from the sun.

Comment: It could be that david has the right interpretation. This is the sort of question where we need an explanation of what the author actually meant; it's a question of interpretation, grading quickly into guesswork, and as such not suitable for ELU.

Comment: Yep, I think this is right. And guess what? Three days of cider vinegar on a cotton ball taped to them will remove them.

Answer (score 1):

It is a literary device akin to '[Antiphrasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiphrasis)'.

Comment: This is not in agreement with other answers, where actual pluses are discussed. Where have you seen 'benevolent skin cancer' used antiphrastically?

Answer (score 1):

Benevolent is used in the sense that the skin cancer would take the old man's life sooner rather than later, contrasted against the potentially long and tortuous ravages that old age sometimes brings.

Comment: Is this your own theory or is this something the author has expressed elsewhere?